# What do I miss in my compare list prolog program?

Tags: prolog

```
isgreater([H1|T1],[H2|T2],D):-
  H1 > H2,isgreater(T1,T2,['Yes'|D]).

isgreater([H1|T1],[H2|T2],D):-
  H1 =< H2,isgreater(T1,T2,['No'|D]).

isgreater([],[],D).
```

The ideal output should be

```
{No,No,No,No,Yes}
```

This is the trace

```
 Call: (10) isgreater([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], _49600) ? creep
   Call: (11) 1>4 ? creep
   Fail: (11) 1>4 ? creep
   Redo: (10) isgreater([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], _49600) ? creep
   Call: (11) 1=<4 ? creep
   Exit: (11) 1=<4 ? creep
 * Call: (11) isgreater([2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4],  ('No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Call: (12) 2>4 ? creep
   Fail: (12) 2>4 ? creep
 * Redo: (11) isgreater([2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4],  ('No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Call: (12) 2=<4 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 2=<4 ? creep
 * Call: (12) isgreater([3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4],  ('No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Call: (13) 3>4 ? creep
   Fail: (13) 3>4 ? creep
 * Redo: (12) isgreater([3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4],  ('No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Call: (13) 3=<4 ? creep
   Exit: (13) 3=<4 ? creep
 * Call: (13) isgreater([4, 5], [4, 4],  ('No'| 'No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Call: (14) 4>4 ? creep
   Fail: (14) 4>4 ? creep
 * Redo: (13) isgreater([4, 5], [4, 4],  ('No'| 'No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Call: (14) 4=<4 ? creep
   Exit: (14) 4=<4 ? creep
 * Call: (14) isgreater([5], [4],  ('No'| 'No'| 'No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Call: (15) 5>4 ? creep
   Exit: (15) 5>4 ? creep
 * Call: (15) isgreater([], [],  ('Yes'| 'No'| 'No'| 'No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
 * Exit: (15) isgreater([], [],  ('Yes'| 'No'| 'No'| 'No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
 * Exit: (14) isgreater([5], [4],  ('No'| 'No'| 'No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
 * Exit: (13) isgreater([4, 5], [4, 4],  ('No'| 'No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
 * Exit: (12) isgreater([3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4],  ('No'| 'No'| _49600)) ? creep
 * Exit: (11) isgreater([2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4],  ('No'| _49600)) ? creep
   Exit: (10) isgreater([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], _49600) ? creep
```

I miss some points here, but I just can't figure it out.

- The program can only return a true value.
- I can only append an element in the front of the list.
- I can not get D when it is the case isgreater([],[],D).

Comment: me, I miss *whitespace* in your program. but it's of course entirely subjective. :) (just joking) --- (but really, with the whitespace added, I could see that) `greater( T1, T2, 'Yes'|D )` should probably be `greater( T1, T2, ['Yes'|D] )`.

Comment: Thank you, but that's a typo.  I don't know why it was missing when I pasted it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem as following:

```
isgreater([H1|T1], [H2|T2], ['Yes'|D]) :- % solution is ['Yes'|D] if
  H1 > H2,                                % H1 is greater than H2 and
  isgreater(T1, T2, D).                   % D is the solution for the small
                                          % instance of the problem

isgreater([H1|T1], [H2|T2], ['No'|D]):-   % analogous to the last case
  H1 =< H2,
  isgreater(T1, T2, D).

isgreater([], [], []).                   % solution is empty if both lists are empty!
```

Running example:

```
?- isgreater([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 4, 4, 4, 4], A).
A = ['No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'] ;
false.

?- isgreater([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 1, 5, 3, 2], A).
A = ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes'] ;
false.

?- isgreater([], [], A).
A = [].
```

Comment: Thank you! I  attempted this just now but I did not realize that I still put isgreater([], [], D) instead of  isgreater([], [], []). That helps a lot !.